# "fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory" while installing OpenCV on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, ubuntu

I'm installing opencv for Python in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from the official OpenCV release here https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html

after creating the build directory and entering cmake ../ the moment I enter the command to make it's giving me the following error - 
Previously I've used OpenCV on Windows. I'm new in Ubuntu. Please help.

```
In file included from /home/avi/opencv/modules/core/test/test_precomp.hpp:12:0,
                 from /home/avi/opencv/build/modules/core/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
/home/avi/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.hpp:66:12: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
 #  include <Eigen/Core>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.cxx.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.cxx.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1287: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find the solution for me in this post so I may as well share it if somebody comes by.

**Problem :** The include was looking for an include called Eigen while I installed Eigen3.

**Solution :** Create a soft link to create a directory called Eigen that redirect to Eigen3.

> sudo ln -s /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen /usr/include/Eigen

https://www.programmersought.com/article/44372970691/

Answer (score 2):

Go to `/home/avi/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.hpp` file.

Edit the line: `# include <Eigen/Core>` to `# include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>`

Read more about this error from [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14868).

Comment: Thanks. I actually had to resolve it by uninstalling all the dependencies and installing again. It worked!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `OpenCV` did not find `Eigen` where it was expecting.
Supposing you installed `Eigen`:

```
sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev
```

The most correct way would be for you to specify to `OpenCV` where you installed `Eigen` by setting the variable `EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH`, usually to `\usr\include`, but check your system.

Another option, instead of editing the OpenCV code, is to create some links between where you installed Eigen, and where OpenCV expects it to be:

```
cd /usr/include
sudo ln -sf eigen3/Eigen Eigen
sudo ln -sf eigen3/unsupported unsupported
```